# 500 error for long url iis7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, url, iis-7

I was getting 404 errors for some long URLs on a website I'm developing. After a bit of digging I discovered that this occurs when the length of certain aspects of the URL exceed configurable limits in IIS7. In this case the *maxQueryString* attribute of the *requestLimits* property needed to be increased in the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" maxAllowedContentLength="4096" maxUrl="8192" >
    </requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This fixed the problem instantly on my development server but on the remote server I now get:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is
>   a problem with the resource you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be
>   displayed.

And that's all the information it gives me.

Comment: Why do you have such large URLs in the first place? This is going to make problems either way.

Comment: This is weird. The error should be HTTP 414: Way Too F#%&ing Long  (http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/HTTP-414-Way-Too-Fing-Long.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Flash to send the data as POST, so it won't be appended to the URL. [Here's some sample code](http://snipplr.com/view/4487/as3-sending-data-using-post/). Also, you may need to change the server side to look for the data as POST instead of GET.

Comment: I've got a a lot of parameters like "c=32&c=33&c=34...." which map nicely to a List<int> parameter on the action method. With Post it doesn't look so simple

Comment: I don't know anything about the asp side, but if you don't see a good way to get the data out of POST easily, open a question on it - because that's your problem, not this. ;)  Even if you get this working, it's just going to fail again when someone's browser or toolbar or add-on truncates the URL. (It seems IE has a limit of 2048 chars, or used to.) POST is the correct approach for what you're doing.

Comment: You are not answering to the question

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your hoster/production-server is running Windows Server 2008 (or 2008 R2)?
The settings you are describing above are only valid for IIS 7+.

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008 - Web Edition

Answer (score 0):

You should not use such long URLs. Among other reasons, at least one of the common toolbars (Bing, Yahoo, Google) will break them, producing just such errors. Users will blame you.

I know this because one of my users was having just such a problem with a legacy app. When I removed the toolbars (she had all three installed!), the problem went away.

Comment: I need to send hundred of parameters through the querystring from Flash I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: @Chris Porter: There's not a way to POST data from Flash?

Answer (score 0):

A GET request is only limited by a browser's limit on the length of the URL string.
In IE it is 2,083 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path. Other browsers do not have a clearly defined limit on the length of the URL string. These articles might be helpful to you.

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427

RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1," does not specify any requirement for URL length, so browsers are free to stipulate what they deem fit.

therefore you should use POST instead of GET if it's fits within your requirements