# Hosted angular 2 cli on azure when I got error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: angular, azure, hosting

I am learning angular 2 and trying to host an app on azure using git.I have no knowledge of git . I am simply following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJCIJZBMDmY). I have already hosted an simple app before

After pushing my app on azure I am getting the error

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

I am using angular cli so I couldn't find web.config as suggested by other answers on stackoverflow. How to config about setting other environments like angular2 cli where i can't find web.config

Comment: this error related to server and folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check out @stas.ivash's answer to find the `web.config` file in [Host Angular2 app with routing in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786139/host-angular2-app-with-routing-in-azure).

> Angular 2 by default uses HTML5 routing, you either have to map all
>   server requests to index.html by adding the following to web.config
>
> ```
> <rewrite>
>     <rules>
>         <rule name="redirect all" stopProcessing="true">
>             <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
>             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
>                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
>             </conditions>
>             <action type="Rewrite" url="PATH TO INDEX.HTML" appendQueryString="true" />
>         </rule>
>     </rules>
> </rewrite>
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response.But from what I understood after reading the answer was to find the web.config file is in the root folder of the site.But I can't find any of those files in my angular 2 app(I am also using angular cli).So Kindly provide me a detailed answer . Thank you

Comment: Just put the web.config file into `/dist` folder and then push it to the remote repository.